# Can a project be build even missing a lib?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

There is a Visual Studio project which refers to `opencv_world440.lib` but it does not seem to be available on vcpkg.
I understand vcpkg has opencv 4.3. In order to proceed I tried to remove `opencv_world440.lib` from
VS, project, properties, linker, input, additional dependencies and the project build successfully then. But when I tried
to run it return an application error

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000017).

I'm not sure what is going on here. May I conclude the project actually does not depend on `opencv_world440.lib`
because it build when I remove it?

Comment: Place the library file in the folder and then try to run the application from that folder or in simple words, place the application and library file in the same folder and then try to run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [dependency walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see if it's something related to libraries. Anyway that error code stands for STATUS_NO_MEMORY as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) which indicates a problem with memory (can also be something OS level!?), sorry but I cannot be more specific.

**EDIT**

"opencv_world" appears to be just one DLL holding all the OpenCV modules, making it easier to distribute. The alternative is to have one library per module. So I guess if you have all the other libraries and it builds, you don't need opencv_world. In few worlds you cannot build a project if you don't have all the necessary libs.

Comment: May I conclude the project actually does not depend on opencv_world440.lib because it build when I remove it?

Comment: Yes, I think so.. I did a little research on opencv_world and edited my reply.